# NetMQ; Send message from C#, receive with Py, finite state machine

Tags: c#, python

I trying to do a basic message transfer from a C# program to a python script, and I think I have a state machine mismatch - request clarification.  My python script is part of a larger system and can't be changed; I need to get my C# to work with it.  I'm getting an Rep.XSend finite state machine exception.

Here's the python:

```
import zmq

# Create the context and subscriber
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")

# Create a poller
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)

# Filter socket output
print("Receiving messages on all topics.")
socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

try:
     while True:
        # Poll the subscriber, add a timeout so script doesn't hang
        events = poller.poll(1000)
        for event in events:
            recvd = event[0].recv_multipart()
            topic = recvd[0]
            msg = recvd[1:]
            topic = topic.decode("utf-8")

            msg_stat.process_message(topic, msg)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("W: interrupt received, stopping...")
finally:
    # Clean up.
    socket.close()
    context.term()
```

and here's the C#:

```
class Program
{
    public static string IP { get; protected set; }
    public static string Port { get; protected set; }
    public static string Address { get { return "tcp://" + IP + ":" + Port; } }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string msg = "";

        IP = "127.0.0.1";
        Port = "5556";

        AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();
        ResponseSocket server = new ResponseSocket();

        try
        {
            server.Bind(Address);
            Console.WriteLine("Started Server " + Address);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to Bind Server to " + Address);
            NetMQConfig.Cleanup(false);
            return;
        }

        server.SendFrame(msg);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using ResponseSocket  to send messgae. ResponseSocket is a socket to receive message first and than send response message. You can try other socket, e.q. RequestSocket instead or RouterSocket